# weight matter in Hugo not taken in account

Tags: hugo

I had an old site made with Hugo in 2015 with different articles. 
They were properly sorted.

Now using the latest Hugo, they are apparently sorted by date and not by weight.

The directory is organized as follow:

```
content
    docs
        file1.md
        file2.md
layouts
    docs
        single.html
        summary.html
    partials
        css.html
        header.html
        footer.html
    index.html
static
    img1.png
    img2.png
```

The list is displayed in the index file with

```
<div id="idx-content">
{{range .Data.Pages}}
    {{.Render "summary"}}
{{end}}
</div>
```

Unfortunately, the ordering of the file summaries is not sorted by weight.
Adding `.ByWeight` after `.Data.Pages` doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

The weight value in the matter must be bigger than 0.